# ngOptions conflicts with my directive and does not work

Tags: angularjs

I have written a directive for bootstrap popover. The popover directive itself works fine but when i use it with ngOptions, ngOptions does not work and does not bind data to select atribute.
The directive code is here:

```
app.directive("ngPopover", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: { popoverVisible: '=', popoverTitle: "=", popoverContent: "=", popoverTrigger: "@", popoverPlacement: "@" },
        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            if (scope.popoverTrigger) {
                $(angular.element(iElement)).popover({
                    title: scope.popoverTitle,
                    content: scope.popoverContent,
                    trigger: (scope.popoverTrigger) ? scope.popoverTrigger : "manual",
                    placement: (scope.popoverPlacement) ? scope.popoverPlacement : "right"
                });
            }
            scope.$watch(function () { return scope.popoverVisible; }, function () {
                $(angular.element(iElement)).popover('destroy');
                $(angular.element(iElement)).popover({
                    title: scope.popoverTitle,
                    content: scope.popoverContent,
                    trigger: (scope.popoverTrigger) ? scope.popoverTrigger : "manual",
                    placement: (scope.popoverPlacement) ? scope.popoverPlacement : "right"
                });
                if (scope.popoverVisible)
                    $(angular.element(iElement)).popover('show');
                else
                    $(angular.element(iElement)).popover('hide');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Here is my view code:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <button class="pop btn btn-danger" ng-click="show()">Show</button>
        <br />
        <select id="select" ng-options="act for act in activities" ng-model="activity" ng-popover
            popover-visible="visPopover" popover-content="'Content'">
        </select>
        <br />
        <button ng-click="hide()">Hide</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my controller function:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.visPopover = false;
    $scope.activities = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'];
    $scope.activity = 'a1';
    $scope.hide = function () {
        $scope.visPopover = false;
    };
    $scope.show = function () {
        $scope.visPopover = true;
    };
}
```

If there are any other problems or bad practices in my code (specially in writing directive) please let me know!

Update:

Fiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/alisabzevari/sZbjt/1/

Comment: That's because your directive is creating an isolated scope in which   `activities`is not available.

Comment: I thought it is but I changed my directive code to a directive without scope and got my directive properties from attributes but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle with an example?

Comment: @AaronHickman: Updated with jsfiddle link. Note that I am working with bootstrap popover. The directive must show a popover near the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stewie was right!
[AngularJS Developer guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> If multiple directives on the same element request a new scope, only
>   one new scope is created.

So I didn't use scope at all. I got all of my directive properties from attributes. The only trick was that I had to watch one of my attributes popover-visible.
here is the directive code:

```
app.directive("ngPopover", function () {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                    if (iAttrs.popoverTrigger) {
                        $(angular.element(iElement)).popover({
                            title: iAttrs.popoverTitle,
                            content: iAttrs.popoverContent,
                            trigger: (iAttrs.popoverTrigger) ? iAttrs.popoverTrigger : "manual",
                            placement: (iAttrs.popoverPlacement) ? iAttrs.popoverPlacement : "right"
                        });
                    }
                    scope.$watch(function () { return iAttrs.popoverVisible; }, function () {
                        $(angular.element(iElement)).popover('destroy');
                        $(angular.element(iElement)).popover({
                            title: iAttrs.popoverTitle,
                            content: iAttrs.popoverContent,
                            trigger: (iAttrs.popoverTrigger) ? iAttrs.popoverTrigger : "manual",
                            placement: (iAttrs.popoverPlacement) ? iAttrs.popoverPlacement : "right"
                        });
                        if (scope.$eval(iAttrs.popoverVisible))
                            $(angular.element(iElement)).popover('show');
                        else
                            $(angular.element(iElement)).popover('hide');
                    });
                }
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix. The trick is to separate the ng-popover from select.

```
<div ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <button class="pop btn btn-danger" ng-click="show()">Show</button>
        <br />
        <ng-popover popover-visible="visPopover" popover-content="'Content'"></ng-popover>
        <select id="select" ng-options="act for act in activities" ng-model="activity"></select>
        <br />
        <button ng-click="hide()">Hide</button>
    </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.directive("ngPopover", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            popoverVisible: '=',
            popoverTitle: "=",
            popoverContent: "=",
            popoverTrigger: "@",
            popoverPlacement: "@"
        },
        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return scope.popoverVisible;
            }, function () {
                var s = iElement.parent().find("select");
                $(s).popover('destroy');
                $(s).popover({
                    title: scope.popoverTitle,
                    content: scope.popoverContent,
                    trigger: (scope.popoverTrigger) ? scope.popoverTrigger : "manual",
                    placement: (scope.popoverPlacement) ? scope.popoverPlacement : "right"
                });
                if (scope.popoverVisible) $(s).popover('show');
                else $(s).popover('hide');
            });
        }
    };
}).controller("Ctrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.visPopover = false;
    $scope.activities = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'];
    $scope.activity = 'a1';
    $scope.hide = function () {
        $scope.visPopover = false;
    };
    $scope.show = function () {
        $scope.visPopover = true;
    };
});
```

Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sZbjt/4/).

Comment: I doesn't work because my popover directive name is ng-popover. I have to mention that I am trying to use bootstrap popover. I think my question was not explicit enough. I have updated the question with a jsfiddle link

Comment: @alisabzevari You were saying it did not bind data, and if you follow my solution, it binds the data, that's all. Why it doesn't work? Have you tried my solution yet?

Comment: Yes, I tried. But my popover didn't work instead. It is clear that I want both working!

Comment: @alisabzevari I just got time to take another look at it. Try it again.

Comment: Thank you for your consideration and trying to solve my problem. But I am trying to write a general purpose popover. I think this is not a good practice to write a directive that searches for a select near it. I try to fins the actual cause of this problem not the tricks or workarounds of it.

Comment: @alisabzevari I just want to shed some light on the problem. Keep in mind, when you are talking about the generic stuff, it is always good to start with some working prototype, and then you can refactor it to a more generic version. You should try to do that by yourself and not just wait here for anyone to post the answer. Please also be considerate that everyone here is also busy and you should start to work on it. Now you have a working version and I think you can definitely to start work on it and make it generic. Thanks.